# Can I turn off safety prompts on file close?

Tags: notepad++, editing

In Notepad++, I generally run with a bunch of text files that I am using temporarily.
It's annoying that I have to click the confirm prompt when closing a file without saving. Is it possible to turn this alert off and just close the file with a right-click and close?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry Notepad++ doesn't have this option.  Personally I just hit either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (close window) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (close application), then hit <kbd>N</kbd> on the keyboard.  Obviously it would take longer if using the mouse.